# How to convert json to array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have data of json as sample

```
[{"Food":"Orange T1","Total":3},
{"Food":"Blue T2","Total":1},
{"Food":"Green T3","Total":1},
{"Food":"White T4","Total":4}]
```

and i want to convert to array object as

```
[['Orange T1', 3], ['Blue T2', 1], ['Green T3', 1],['White T4', 4]]
```

How I do this and I will use `console.log()` to show data sample.

Comment: do you have an array or a [JSON](http://json.org/) string?

Comment: `.map({food, total} => [food, total])` should do the trick

Comment: I have a data of json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the values of each object.

```js
var array = [{ Food: "Orange T1", Total: 3 }, { Food: "Blue T2", Total: 1 }, { Food: "Green T3", Total: 1 }, { Food: "White T4", Total: 4 }],
    result = array.map(Object.values);
    
console.log(result);
```

If you do not rely on insertation order of objects values, you could use explit keys and their values.

ES6

```js
var array = [{ Food: "Orange T1", Total: 3 }, { Food: "Blue T2", Total: 1 }, { Food: "Green T3", Total: 1 }, { Food: "White T4", Total: 4 }],
    result = array.map(({ Food, Total }) => [Food, Total]);
    
console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var array = [{ Food: "Orange T1", Total: 3 }, { Food: "Blue T2", Total: 1 }, { Food: "Green T3", Total: 1 }, { Food: "White T4", Total: 4 }],
    result = array.map(function (o) { return [o.Food, o.Total]; });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: As the order of properties is *unordered*, this might not work everywhere.

Comment: the order is usually the insertation order, as long as the object does not have keys which could be read as integer. these values are listed first.

Comment: Usually yes, but not necessarily according to the specification.

Comment: Dear Nina Scholz, with case ```result = array.map(({ Food, Total }) => [Food, Total]);``` . It's not working , Are you sure for this ?

Comment: @BrianCrist, it is ES6 syntax, i add ES5.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArr = JSON.parse(yourJson).map((item) => {return [item.Food, item.Total]})

console.log(newArr);
```